# Javascript: regex for parsing quoted strings containing escaped quote - returns unterminated character class

Tags: javascript, regex

Searching for a regex which parses efficiently strings containing escaped quote I ended up with the fallowing regular expression literal:

```
/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/
```

It works well and fast if, for example, used to split a strings like:

```
var str = 'This is a block of text containing a "string with a \" (escaped quote) in it"';

str.split(/("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")/);
```

Now the trouble comes in play when i try to build dynamically the regex making use of the built-in `RegEx` object:

```
/* splits by space characters and 
strings containing escaped quote */
var re = new RegExp("(\\s|\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\")");
```

How noticeable I know that this use case requires to escape metacharacters and quotes. Nevertheless i get the fallowing errors:

Safari says

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing terminating ] for character class
```

Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated character class
```

By the way, the error message returned from Safari give me a little more clue making clear that the regex engine detects a missing closing square bracket, requiring the backslash character before itself to be escaped like so:

```
                                 v               v
var re = new RegExp("(\\s|\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")");
```

but this way I realize that strings containing escaped quote are no more parsed correctly.

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: There far too many backslashes in your regex, for example `\\s` will match a backslash (\\) followed by `s` literally, e.g. `\s` - is this what you want? Please clarify which string you want to split and what the desired output is.

Comment: You just have to double-escape backslashes if you use a string (ie: `\s` becomes `\\s`, \\ becomes \\\\, etc). By the way `/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/` _is_ a `RegExp` object...

Comment: Briefly, I've some c++ source code coming from a `innerHTML` and I need to extract a string like: `"this is a string with escaped \" inside"`.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your first regex that you can use for matching. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qpw3e0by/). No need splitting. Does it work as intended?

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my question: using the regular expression literal it works as excpected, but not using a regex created with a string passed to the `RegEx`Object constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking account also of the comment above, I've examined more in depth the topic and finally, thanks to the observation pointed out by @NullUserException, I got the solution. I've realized that the regex object:

```
var re = new RegExp("(\\s|\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")");
```

didn't work because for a mere oversight I didn't escape correctly the part which detects characters preceded by backslash (escape chars). So, in a string, the sequence `\\.` must be `\\\\.`:

```
var re = new RegExp("(\\s|\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")");
```

Here's a simple live demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/9ctw66pu/